# How to count date (year and week)

Tags: r

How do I count the frequency of dates when they are not ymd but year and week format?

Because I am doing research based on weekly analysis, but the answers I found are related to daily data.

[image: My Sample Data]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. 
This works just fine

```
data1$count <- ave(!is.na(data1$Trdwnt), substr(data1$Trdwnt, 1,7), FUN=sum)
```